# Windows 10 not seeing shared folders

Tags: samba, windows-10, shared-folders

I have a stack of family photos on my Ubuntu 17.10 PC which my wife would like to be able to access from her windows 10 laptop.

The usual methods worked fine with Windows 7; in fact, I have a Windows 7 laptop that sees the folder fine. However, the Ubuntu PC does not show in the list of network places on the Windows 10 machine.

I found a solution [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-linux-samba-shares-from-windows-10/) but either I'm typing in the IP address wrongly or it just isn't working. How do I get the right IP addresses for shared folders, and what else could I try if that fails?

Comment: Does pressing the Windows Key + R then typing in `\\IP_of_Ubuntu\sharename` work?

Answer (score 0):

They show "Next you must enter the IP address of your Samba server (Figure C) in the form of //SERVER_IP/SHARE (Where SERVER_IP is the IP address of your Samba server and SHARE is the name of the share you want to add)."

I'm pretty sure it should be it should have back slashes not forward ones.